# Why "Moderator Tab" not showing on comments plugin?

Tags: facebook

I'm using facebook's comments plugin on my site and on my blog. One of them the "moderator tab" does not appear (like image 1) and in the other it appears (image 2).

I'm administrator/moderator of both applications. Both applications have the fb:app_id attribute. What could I be doing wrong?

Feel free to check the code for both pages:

- Works: http://blog.getninjas.com.br/?p=210
- Don't work: http://getninjas.com.br/categorias/marketing/ofertas/consultoria-de-social-media

Thank you.

[image: Without moderator tab]
[image: With moderator tab]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paste the URL that doesn't work into the URL Linter at http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

The resulting page has an "Errors that must be fixed" section. In this case, Facebook says you have a circular redirect path. I believe the moderator tab is not showing due to the circular redirect error.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with my plugin.
I use the plugin in several pages of my website, and in all the pages the moderation tab was showing up but on page Y.

After some research I did not found anything helpful, but I realized that when I accessed the page Y using https, the moderation tool did not appear, when I accessed it using http the moderation tool appeared.

Voila, that was the solution for my problem.
See ya!